# jQuery slider, how can I pause the autoplay when mouse over?

Tags: jquery, slider, autoplay

Guys, I'm not good on coding, and this little script are really bother me a lot.
I have a slider with autoplay, which is works fine. But I need somebody help me to pause the autoplay when mouse over.
Also, can somebody find a way to play the 1st slide when it reaches the last slide, instead of roll back to the 1st slide?
Thank you so much. And here are the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var currentPosition = 0;
      var slideWidth = 560;
      var slides = $('.slide');
      var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

      // --- autoshow ---------
      function autoshow(){
      //alert('start');
        currentPosition = currentPosition+1 ;
        if(currentPosition==numberOfSlides){
        currentPosition=0;
      }
      // Hide / show controls
      manageControls(currentPosition);
      // Move slideInner using margin-left
      $('#slideInner').animate({
        'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
      });
      timeOut = setTimeout(autoshow, 3000);
      }
      timeOut = setTimeout(autoshow, 3000);
      // ----autoshow -----------

      // Remove scrollbar in JS
      $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

      // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
      slides
        .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
        // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
        .css({
          'float' : 'left',
          'width' : slideWidth
        });

      // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
      $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

      // Insert controls in the DOM
      $('#slideshow')
        .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
        .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');

      // Hide left arrow control on first load
      manageControls(currentPosition);

      // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
      $('.control')
        .bind('click', function(){
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

        // Hide / show controls
        manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#slideInner').animate({
          'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
        });
      });

      // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
      function manageControls(position){
        // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
        if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
        // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
        if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert either so this answer may be wrong but have you tried playing around with the .hover function it may look like something like this.

```
    $('#slideInner').hover(function() { 
      $('#slideInner').stop();
      clearTimeout(ticker_timeout);
```

or something like this

```
    $("#slideInner")
         // when mouse enters, clear the timer if it has been set
         .mouseenter(function() {
           if (timer) { clearInterval(timer) }
        })
        // when mouse goes out, start the slideshow
         .mouseleave(function() {
          timer = setInterval(function() {
              $("#slideInner > div:first")
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo("#slideInner");
        }, 3000);
    })
    // trigger mouseleave for initial slideshow starting
    .mouseleave();
```