# How to automate this slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this slider and I want to automate the process. I used the following code below. I found a way to automate it but then it disabled the buttons. Could you help me out? Also, I would like to know how to pause the slider when someone hovers over it.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: raleway,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: firebrick;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a red background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  color:white;
  background-color: rgba(178,34,34,0.8);
}

.prev:active, .next:active {
  color:white;
  background-color: rgba(178,34,34,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: firebrick;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: salmon;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.dot:hover{  background-color: firebrick;}


/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
.boingInUp {
  animation-name: boingInUp;
}
@keyframes boingInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(50deg);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
.puffIn {
  animation-name: puffIn;
}
@keyframes puffIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: scale(2,2);
    filter: blur(2px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: scale(1,1);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}
.vanishIn {
  animation-name: vanishIn;
}
@keyframes vanishIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: scale(2, 2);
    filter: blur(90px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}
/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides vanishIn fade">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides vanishIn fade">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides vanishIn fade">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center;transform:translateY(-60px);">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out because I am not a professional at Javascript. I got some tips but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: It's okay, I got the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the "window.setInterval" function I added to your javascript, it works for me:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    $( "a.next" ).trigger( "click" );
}, 5000);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using set interval too but it didn't work because I put something different.

Comment: Yea you could write an if else with the condition being hover on the slider image (and buttons).

Comment: could you please create a pen because i can't seem to get that working

Comment: Try this, you'll need to integrate it with your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324987/jquery-slider-how-can-i-pause-the-autoplay-when-mouse-over

Comment: I am not that good with Javascript. I can't seem to get it working.